# How do I parse JSON with Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm using JSON to parse a string. Given an artist name, I'm using the echonest API to print five songs by that artist:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'

puts "Enter an artists name:"
artist_name = gets.chomp


file =open(parsed)

url = URI.parse("http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/songs?    api_key=RYOXFCWIBV9IM0XCU&name=#{artist_name}&format=json&start=0&results=5")
res = Net::HTTP.get_response(url)

#puts res.body

parsed = JSON.parse(res.body)


parsed{'songs'}.each do |song| 
puts song{'title'} 
end
```

Comment: Why did you remove all the code from the question?

Comment: FIrst time ever getting negative votes for a question... wasn't sure my code would help anyone.

Comment: You're getting down votes because you removed all the code. The question doesn't make any sense without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take out the line `file = open(parsed)`. What is it there for, anyway?

Likewise, in Ruby hashes are accessed with `[key]`, not `{key}` as in some other languages like Perl.

```
parsed['response']['songs'].each do |song| puts song['title'] end
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to open the already parsed JSON, just iterate it. Also replace `{` with `[`:

```
parsed["response"]["songs"].each do |song|
    p song["title"]
end
```

Comment: still undefined method error 'each' for nil:NilClass <noMethodError>

Comment: You must have to check if there is "song" key in your data. Try to print the parsed data: p parsed.

Comment: printing the parsed data works. I get the same output as put res.body

Comment: updated the post to include json parsed outpout